# Get Sublime to respect Vim syntax highlighting hints

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

Vagrant files, for instance, contain code like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
```

Is there a way to get Sublime to do something useful with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sublime automatically chooses the syntax highlighting mode based on the file's extension. If you would like a certain extension to be associated with a particular language, just open the file, then choose **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as...`** and pick the language you'd like.

If you are working with files without an extension, or would just like finer-grained control, check out the [`ApplySyntax`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ApplySyntax) plugin. It allows you to define regexes based on file name and file contents, including shebang lines. It could very easily be modified in the settings to read Vim setting strings. It already includes a setting for `Vagrantfile`, so for your particular example you wouldn't need to modify anything.

Comment: Ok, that's a slightly different angle, but ApplySyntax seems to solve the problem, so thank you.